# Min-max scaling vs standardizing in LASSO

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, regularization, feature-scaling

I know that it is recommended to have features on the same scale for LASSO, such that the scale does not affect the penalty. However, does it matter whether or not features are scaled using $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ or  $\frac{x-x_{min}}{x_{max}-x_{min}}$?

This is purely for prediction purposes if that is important.

Comment: Scaling is technique to bring every feature on one scale. You can try multiple scaling methods, but there are some pros and cons associated with them. Give this a read: https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-feature-scaling-bcc0ad75cb35

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it doesn't seem like the article answer my question.